# App name not displayed in iTunes

Tags: ios, itunes, submission

My app just got approved today by apple. When I look in iTunes however, I can see my app, but the name does not appear. It is literally an icon without a title. Also, the screenshots are missing. It also says that it is not available in the US store, but I still can still see it (without the title). Whats wrong? Is it something I did, or something apple did? Is it likely to correct itself? Maybe an issue processing?

Thanks in advance,
Michael

EDIT: It is not something that I have done wrong. Apple has messed up many app titles including some highly ranking ones. When do you think they will notice?

Answer (score 1):

This could be a data center issue. Especially after just approving apps, it takes a while before they turn up in search results (indexing), show the correct images or even turn up on different devices. This is all the result of different devices accessing different servers, indexes only being generated every x minutes/hours and content networks not being fully synchronized at avery point in time (sometimes not being able to download, while the app already appears in the store).

Give it some time, it usually takes 3 to 4 hours before every store / server seems to be up to date. It can take even longer before search indexes are updated.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm sure it will sort out. It got approved around 11:00 this morning, so it has been many hours.